# Reducing the time for rolling hash

Tags: c++, performance, strings

I tried this problem below and solved it in O(test_cases * string_length * pattern_length) complexity involving three nested loops. I want to know how can I further decrease time. I figured as much:

1: I'm comparing few patterns more than once.

2: Should find a way to not repeat the comparisons which I am unable to do.

The problem is as below:-

> We are given a string S and a Pattern P. You need to find all matches of hash of P in string S. Also, print the index (0 based) at which the pattern's hash is found. If no match is found, print -1.
>
> Note: All the matches should have same length as pattern P.
>
> The hash of pattern P is calculated by summing the values of characters as they appear in the alphabets table. For reference, a is 1, b is 2, ...z is 26. Now, using the mentioned values, hash of ab is 1+2=3.
>
> Input:
>
> The first line of input contains T denoting the number of testcases. T testcases follow. Each testcase contains two lines of input. The first line contains the string S. The second line contains the pattern P.
>
> Output:
>
> For each testcase, in a new line, print the matches and index separated by a space. All the matches should be printed in their own separate lines.
>
> Constraints:
>
> 1 <= T <= 100
> 1 <= |S|, |P| <= 10⁵
>
> Examples:
>
> Input:
> 1
> bacdaabaa
> aab
> Output:
> aab 4
> aba 5
> baa 6
> Explanation:
>
> Testcase1:
> P is aab, and S is bacdaabaa
> Now, the hash of P: aab is 1+1+2=4
> In the string S, the hash value of 4 is obtained by the following:
>
> aab=1+1+2=4, at index 4
> aba=1+2+1=4, at index 5
> baa=2+1+1=4, at index 6

My code in C++ :-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
long ind,j,test,kal;
cin>>test; //testcases' input//
for(ind=0;ind<test;ind++)
{
   long len1,len2,sum1=0,sum2=0;  
   string s1,s2,s3;  //s1 for the input string,s2 for pattern,s3 to print the patterns that we find//
   cin>>s1>>s2;
   len1=s1.size();       //length of input string//
   len2=s2.size();       //length of pattern //
   for(j=0;j<len2;j++)
   {
       sum2=sum2+(int)s2[j]-96;   //doing the hash sum of pattern first so that i need not do pattern matching//
   }
   for(j=0;j<=len1-len2;j++)    //iterate len1-len2 times since we get those many distinct or duplicate patterns//
   {
       for(kal=j;kal<j+len2;kal++)  //iterate j+len2 times which is size of the pattern each time//
       {
           sum1=sum1+(int)s1[kal]-96; //updating the sum obtained//
           s3.push_back(s1[kal]);  //since we also need to print the pattern which has the hash sum//
       }
       if(sum1==sum2)        //if the sum matches print the string and starting index//
       cout<<s3<<" "<<j<<endl;
       s3.erase();           //clear the string for next testcase//
       sum1=0;               //clear the sum for next testcase//
   }
}
return 0;}
```

Please suggest changes that reduces the time.

Comment: As a side note: this whole thing is solved really fast in unix 'grep' I think: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12629749/how-does-grep-run-so-fast

Comment: Actually, this explanation is a demo, and it's brilliantly easy to follow: https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/moore/best-ideas/string-searching/fstrpos-example.html

Comment: @JCx thanks for that man, I'm also learning Linux programming, this is of some help to me.

Answer (score 13):

This code does not implement a rolling hash. For every iteration of the main loop, the hash is reset and then entirely re-calculated from nothing with an inner loop. A rolling hash would remove a character from the hash and then add a new character, doing only a constant amount of work per sub-string.

There are some edge-cases for you to work out, but main element of the technique is this:

```
hash = hash - s1[kal - len2] + s1[kal]
```

No inner loop. Also no `- 96` because it is cancelled out.

Comment: Thanks!This is not exactly the rolling hash algorithm , it was just named like that.The code i wrote works the way i wanted , its just that the time needs to reduced.

Comment: @Ananthhokage using a rolling hash should help with the time

Comment: so i should learn rolling hash algorithm first?

Comment: @Ananthhokage well it's really simple, it comes down to that one line of code that I wrote above.. with suitable initialization of course. In general with a hash function that also involves multiplying the hash by a constant, there may be some trickier math concepts involved (modular multiplicative inverse etc) but the code is still really simple.

Comment: (The -96 is ill-conceived right from the start, just offsetting the sum by *-96\*len(P)*.) Multiplying the checksum with some constant before adding in another item is one way to get a *position sensitive checksum*, which would reduce the matches to just *aab 4* in the example (in all likelihood: in general, there may be collisions with any fixed size summary of something unlimited in size).

Answer (score 12):

So far, your code has some general problems that are much more urgent than performance:

1. You are `using namespace std;`.  This is an extremely bad habit and will ruin your life ("this is a contest and I write everything in main" is not an acceptable excuse).  See [Why is `using namespace std;` considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721).
2. The `main` function is very long and a reader cannot tell at a glance what it does.  If you need so many comments, you should consider refactoring your code.  (Also, why do your comments end with `//`?)
3. You are not making enough use of the standard library.
4. There is too little space.  And the indentation is inconsistent.
5. The variable names are not helpful.  What is `sum1`?  `s3`?
6. `j++` is being used instead of the correct `++j`.  See [Difference between pre-increment and post-increment in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/484462).

Also, please avoid `std::endl` when not necessary.  Use `'\n'` instead.  See [C++: `std::endl` vs `\n`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/213907).

And `str.erase()` is much less intuitive than `str.clear()`.  (In fact, I didn't know until today that `erase` can be invoked this way.)

Here's I would write the same code, at the very least: (30 seconds code, not tested comprehensively)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <string>

int hash_code(const std::string& pattern)
{
    // note: c - 'a' + 1 is not portable
    return std::accumulate(pattern.begin(), pattern.end(), 0,
                           [](int x, char c){ return x + (c - 'a' + 1); });
}

void search(const std::string& string, const std::string& pattern)
{
    const int pattern_hash = hash_code(pattern);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i + pattern.size() <= string.size(); ++i) {
        auto str = string.substr(i, pattern.size());
        if (hash_code(str) == pattern_hash)
            std::cout << str << " " << i << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        std::string string, pattern;
        std::cin >> string >> pattern;
        search(string, pattern);
    }
}
```

(Also, the input style is quite strange, I have to admit, but that seems to be beyond your control.)

Incidentally, I don't think you properly implemented the sentence "If no match is found, print -1."

Comment: First of all thanks for answering here and responding to my other question on stackoverflow XD.I tried your your code (copy_pasted it prior to examining it) it still gave me timeout(should be less than 0.6 secs).I agree i need to use libraries more and figure out which ones are effective keeping in mind the time constraints.If you wanna try out the question yourself [link]https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/contest-problem/rolling-hash510436075531/0/  .Thanks again!

Comment: As a standalone statement (like in a for loop) it does not really matter if you use `++i` or `i++`. Saying that pre-increment is the "correct" one is a matter of taste.

Comment: @danielspaniol yes I know about that but am afraid I might get downvoted even if I remotely sound confronting their opinion lol.

Comment: @Ananthhokage No, of course not.  There is absolutely no reason to downvote you for that.  If you challenge my opinion, I will happily discuss with you.

Comment: @danielspaniol For some strange reason I didn't noticed your comment, sorry for that.  My take is that in theory they are indeed the same in this particular situation, but `++i` does logically what we want to do here, and in general `++i` is faster than `i++`, so sticking to `++i` is probably a good idea.  A discarded value `i++` just look as "wrong" as `*(&x) + char(1) + 2 + 0["\003"] - (short)5 + 9` in place of `x + 10` to many of us (well, that's a bit exaggerated), also any decent compiler should generate equivalent code for them.

Comment: @L.F. Thank you! I just read this thread and now understand your point [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-i-and-i-in-c

Answer (score 1):

Two more things about something like
`sum=sum+(int)pattern[j]-96;`:
- 96 is a *magic number*: The reader is left to figure out what it means here.  `('a' - 1)` is portable and suggestive.
- C has *assignment operators* to avoid repeating an "operand that gets assigned the result":
 `sum += pattern[j] - 'a' + 1;`

You don't need to collect the characters from the input string contributing to the checksum: They stay right there.

I don't see *comparing patterns more than once*.
For patterns of same length, checksums for parts of the input string get recomputed - if so inclined, try to exploit that.
For patterns P1 of length l1 and P2, |P2| = l2 = l1 + 1, the checksum to compare with checksum S2 of P2 is just "one computation step from S1" - but *don't try to exploit this*:
That way lies madness. (What if there was a P3: l3 = l1 + l2? P4:  l4 = l3 - 1?)